# GTK+ under Windows to display gui under Linux

Tags: linux, windows, gtk

I want to write an application for Windows which displays its GUI on a Linux machine.
My idea is to use GTK+, compiler would be MS Visual C++, I know that the gtk libraries are available for Windows, but need a push into the right direction to start.

Will I need some kind of client app on the Linux side as well?

Comment: Windows is not "network-transparent" as X is. You will definitely need a client on the Linux side, but how do you intend to push information from the server to the client?

Comment: Not sure if Gtk+ render backend "broadway" covers this, but it might be worth a shot of google.